# if else condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am in learning process of linq to sql.

is it possible to write these following condition in linq to sql?

condition 1

```
var query1 = 
             if
             from q in db.Students
             q.fees =="paid" && q.activites == "good" && count == 0
             select q 

              save "OK" to the property result. 

          else 
             from q in db.Students
             q.fees =="paid" && q.activites == "good" && count == 2
             select q 
             save "better" to the property result. 

            else
            from q in db.Students
            q.fees =="paid" && q.activites == "good" && count > 2
            select q 
            save "bad" to the property result. 


  private string _result; 
  public string Result
    {
        get { return this._result; ; }
        set { this._result;  = value; }
    }
```

kindly guide.

Updated EDIT :

```
   var query1 =                  
             (from q in db.Students
             q.fees =="paid" && q.activites == "good" 
             select q).Any(); 

  if(count ==0 && query1 == true)
  {
    this.Result = "OK"
  }
  esle if(count == 2  && query1 == true)
  {
    this.Result = "better"
  }
  esle 
  {
    this.Result = "bad"
  }
```

will this be an approach ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909926/linq-if-else-condition/15909991#_=_ see

Comment: Since this is code-side, why not just use a regular if-else pattern and put the necessary linq queries in those blocks?

Comment: can you please give an tiny example

Comment: @user1221765 Tor Andersson's link explains everything.

Comment: Be aware that LINQ to SQL is being superceded by Entity Framework. You'll be able to transfer some of the knowledge, but I'd recommend learning EF instead.

Comment: @user1221765, did you intend for your "count" condition in your `where` clause to indicate the number of rows returned?

Comment: I have already computed the count value, I will edit my question

Comment: One more question. Are you just using `Convert.ToBoolean(query1)` to see if your query returned any records?

Comment: It is working only when I use if(count ==0) & then it is returns a value .. when I use if(count ==0 && Convert.ToBoolean(query1) == true) I get an exception saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is all code-side, you can just use use a regular if-else pattern after you run your LINQ query.

Example:

```
var query1 =                  
         from q in db.Students
         q.fees =="paid" && q.activites == "good" 
         select q;

if(count ==0 && query1.Count() > 0)
{
    this.Result = "OK";
}
else if(count == 2  && query1.Count() > 0)
{
    this.Result = "better";
}
else 
{
    this.Result = "bad";
}
```

Since the LINQ is just being used to determine whether the records exist, though, I would recommend using the [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) method.

```
var recordsFound = db.Students.Any(q => q.fees =="paid" && q.activites == "good");

if(count == 0 && recordsFound)
{
    this.Result = "OK";
}
else if(count == 2 && recordsFound)
{
    this.Result = "better";
}
else 
{
    this.Result = "bad";
}
```

Comment: I am going to try and get back, thanks indeed for the update @valverij

Comment: can you please explain what does count()>0 means herein the first solution ?

Comment: Since query1 will be of the type `Enumerable<Student>`, the `.Count()` just returns the number of elements contained within the collection. If this was not your intent, then let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: the second one looks better to me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are always querying on the same conditions and the only thing that you are reacting to conditionally on is the number of results returned. You could just get the results with a where condition, and then put an if statement around the results count.

```
var count = (from q in db.Students
where q.fees == "paid" && q.activities == "good"
select q).Count();

if(count == 0){
     //do something
 }
 else if(count == 2){
     //do something 
 }
 ///etc...
```

Comment: Pls see my above comments, I have already tried this and it is working fine with count. I have problem when comparing the count & the query1.